# Norm of matrix and property

Tags: operator-theory, operator-algebras

$$A=  \begin{pmatrix}
  0 & 1  & i \\
  1 & 1 & 2 \\
  -i & 2  & 3 
 \end{pmatrix}
$$
Calculate $\|A\|$ and demonstrate $\|A^+A\|=\|A\|^2 $.

Which is the fastest way to resolve this?

I can demonstrate that property using first a $\leq$ and then a $\geq$, and prove that if the two statements are valid then it's $=$ .

And $A^+A $ would mean that it is a Hermitian matrix.

But I'm not sure how to calculate $\|A\|$. Should it be the maximum of the eigenvalues of the matrix?

Comment: What do you know about the norm of a matrix?

Comment: Should be the sup of $\frac{|Ax|}{x} $, formally

Comment: Are you sure that's your matrix? It is Hermitian, which simplifies everything, but still the [exact expressions for theh eigenvalues](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=eigenvalues+%7B%7B0,1,i%7D,%7B1,1,2%7D,%7B-i,2,3%7D%7D) appear to be nasty.

Comment: (too late to edit). In particular, $\|A\|=4,4709...$

Comment: @martinargerami Yes, that's why I was looking for a faster way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your matrix is Hermitian, so $$\|A\|=\max\{|\lambda|:\ \lambda\in\sigma(A)\}.$$ And so is $A^*A$, so this problem is only about calculating eigenvalues. Which are a pain for the concrete matrix given.

Comment: Can I prove that it is Hermitian without calculating the eigenvalues?

Comment: The eigenvalues will never tell you if the matrix is hermitian. But here you can check right away that   $A^*=A $.

Comment: Does $A^*=A$ implies $||A^*A||=||A||^2 $ ?

Comment: The equality  $\|A\|^2=\|A^*A\|$ holds for any  matrix, irrespective of whether it's Hermitian or not.